# Golang. Replace module path for package that are not real go packages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, open-telemetry

There is this package https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto
which contains protobuf definitions only. To generate golang code one must type:

```
make gen-go
```

and go build fails with following message:

```
build opentel: cannot load github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/common/v1: module github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto@latest found (v0.11.0), but does not contain package github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/common/v
```

I've tried to replace one path with another in go.mod file but apparently I'm not too good at it. How can I make it work?

I've copied those generated files to

```
$GOPATH/src/opentelemetry-proto/gen/go
```

what should I put in import statement inside my main package?

Comment: I cloned the repo and, from within in ran `make gen-go` and it generated a `./gen` directory without error. The Make process uses `docker run` to run protoc and so you should (!?) not receive errors. Are you trying to generate the source from the protos differently somehow?

Comment: Ah, you updated the question already ;-)

Comment: @DazWilkin yeah :), the problem is. How to import local package to my main program. If I remove go.mod and go.sum it works but then I can not import other packages. This is some nightmare.

Comment: It is a little messy and how they've done it, is not how I would do it... Will add an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of challenges with the way the Go sources are generated. I assume that the repo authors are aiming for consistency across languages and for `GOPATH` and `GO MODULES` use-cases with Go.... so, yes, gnarly for them and us.

Here's a (!?) solution:

Assuming you're in `/path/to/somedir` and it contains a clone of the `opentelemetry-proto` and ``my-module` at the same level, i.e.:

```sh
.
├── my-module
└── opentelemetry-proto
```

1. `make gen-go` as before. This should create `./opentelemetry-proto/gen`
2. In `./opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto` go `go mod init github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto`:

```sh
.
├── gen
└── go.mod
```

3. From within `my-module`, `go mod init my-module` and then:

`go.mod`:

```
module my-module

go 1.17

require (
    github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto v0.11.0
)

replace (
    github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto => ../opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto
```

> **NOTE** With `GOPATH` paths down to packages are required (they're not using Go Modules) and so, if we were using `GOPATH`, we could `GOPATH=${GOPATH}:${PROTO_GEN_GO_DIR}/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto`

And then, e.g.

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    v1 "github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/collector/metrics/v1"
)

func main() {
    // E.g.
    _ = v1.ExportMetricsServiceRequest{}
}
```

Explanation:

`make gen-go` does not create a Module but we can create one.

The Module is implicit from the path under `gen/go` i.e. `github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto`

Then, from our project, we can `replace` to provide a local path to it. The path is the path to the clone, then back down to our newly-created `go.mod`.

The import path is the path **from** the Module (i.e. that excessively convoluted replace path) to whichever package we're interested in.

> **NOTE** Commonly protobuf imports are pb but I've used `v1`.

What I would do:

I think the Module of generated code should match its repo. If `opentelemetry-proto` were mine, I'd generate the sources into the repo root without `gen/go`

As this would -- IMO -- simplify everything to:

```
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto => ../opentelemetry-proto
```

And:

```golang
import (
    v1 "github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/collector/metrics/v1"
)
```

Comment: Of course it worked but I am not an expert in Go dependency system so I have to ask. :)
Why
`go mod init github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto`
inside
`./opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto`
and not any other folder? Or maybe this does not matter as long as long as other things "match"?
By match I mean this one for example?
`replace (
    github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto => ../opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto
`

Comment: It may be possible to omit placing the `go.mod` in the generated code tree but, the only way it works for me is with one. `go.mod` defines a Module (and references Modules). Modules are an aggregation of Packages. The Module root is in `./opentelemetry-proto/gen/go/github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto` because this is where the root of the generated Golang sources is placed. If this were my repo, I'd configure `protoc` to generate the sources into the repo root's (github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto` to avoid this redundancy.

Comment: I assume the package authors need to consider Golang `GOPATH` uses as well as non-Golang uses and so they chose this solution.

Comment: Thank you for all your help I really appreciate it.
btw Do you have some link to good tutorial, article where can I actually learn about this Go dependencies system because as you can see I'm not that good at it (although I am quite good Go coder ;) )

Comment: You're welcome. The following are useful. I've mostly learned from trial and error: https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules and https://golang.org/ref/mod